# replace backslash with frontslash using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the URL like  \abcfolder\cdf\ghi now i need to convert the URL like //abcfolder/cdf/TCSPMs/ghi .I used the following code but its not working . Need your suggestions.

```
string url = "\\abcfolder\cdf\ghi";
url.replace("\\" , "//")
url.replace("\" , "/")
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: For the clear reference i added the url like that .But actualy i get the value from service

Answer (score -1):

first, javascript doesn't use the "string" variable declaration, just use `var yourVarName = "this is a string"`

second, your string should escape backslashes to work properly.

below i have put an example of how to replace the backslashes with forward slashes:

```js
var url = "\\abcfolder\\cdf\\ghi";
alert(url.replace(/\\/g,"/"));
```